# VSCode extension dependencies installation when installing extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, dependencies, vscode-extensions

I've create an extension for visual studio code.
In my package.json, I've a big list of dependencies :

```
"dependencies": {
        "@types/fs-extra": "^8.0.0",
        "@types/puppeteer-core": "^2.0.0",
        "@types/yamljs": "^0.2.30",
        "anchor-markdown-header": "^0.5.7",
        "clone": "^2.1.2",
        "dedent": "^0.7.0",
        "front-matter": "^3.0.2",
        "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
        "get-port": "^5.1.1",
        "highlight.js": "^9.18.0",
        "localized-resource-manager": "^1.2.0",
        "markdown-it": "^10.0.0",
        "markdown-it-anchor": "^5.2.5",
        "markdown-it-checkbox": "^1.1.0",
        "markdown-it-emoji": "^1.4.0",
        "markdown-it-table-of-contents": "^0.4.4",
        "multi-integer-range": "^4.0.8",
        "mustache": "^4.0.0",
        "puppeteer-core": "^2.1.1",
        "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
        "serve-handler": "^6.1.2",
        "simple-git": "^1.131.0",
        "string-template": "^1.0.0",
        "svn-spawn": "^0.1.6",
        "temp-filesystem": "^1.1.3",
        "transliteration": "^2.1.8",
        "twemoji": "^12.1.5",
        "utf8": "^3.0.0",
        "website-scraper": "^4.2.0",
        "yamljs": "^0.3.0"
    },
```

My problem is that I need to embed all these dependencies (and their dependencies) in my package node_modules folder.

So my package consists now of more than 5000 files and more than 300 MB.

Is there a way to not include the node_modules folder in the package but tell to vscode to install them when installing my extension ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes I used WebPack, I don't know if it's the best solution, but it's a little better